# POST value from client to server, then assigned it to a label, is immediately lost - Why?

Tags: c#, jquery, post, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I want to send a simple value from my client side .aspx web page using JQuery or javascript, to my server side code-behind (C#). From this data, I want to populate some asp.net labels.

Problem is, although I can get the data at the server, assigning any value to anything is instantly lost as soon as the thread leaves the code-behind method. Why? And how can I prevent it??? Advanced thanks.

This is what I have so far...

Client side within  ContentPlaceHolderID="head" tags (MyWebPage.aspx is within a Masterpage):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
  <script>
    $.post("MyWebPage.aspx",
      {
         myKey:"Hello World"
      },
     function () {});
   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Server side .cs

```
Page_Load(
      if (Request.Params["myKey"] != null)
      {
          if (Request.Params["myKey"] == "Hello World")
             {
                 Label1.Text = "Hello World";
                 Label2.Text = Request.Params["myKey"].ToString();
                 HiddenField.Value = "Hello World";
                 // All values are assigned here, but...
             } 
      }    
);
```

Page displays; all the above assigned values are lost :-( Why???

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call submits an asynchronous request to the server, which handles the request and sends back a response. You're then expected to do something with that response, but you're not, because you've passed an empty callback function to `$.post()`.

What's returned by the server won't magically be placed onto your page, that's not how AJAX works, you'll have to do it yourself (or use the jQuery `.load()` function which *does* do it).

```
$.post("MyWebPage.aspx", {
     myKey:"Hello World"
}, function (responseText) {
    // do something with responseText here
});
```

Comment: Arr... I see my fundamental problem. Thanks!

Comment: What's the server-side coding to send data back to function(responeText) - Ideally, using two parameters. Can find lots of examples for the client side, just not the server